# Is it normal and expected that I cannot use the weight text fields to set weight?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

I am attempting to use the weight text fields in Drupal taxonomy to set weights. My expectation is that I can use the weight field to set the weight. My question, therefore is, is it normal and expected that I cannot use the weight text fields to set weight? If this is the normal, expected behavior, then I would proposition that this does not smoothly align with the user experience.

I have [recorded the issue here](https://youtu.be/--gDei_TQSY) to clearly demonstrate what the problem is.

PS: I am fairly new to Drupal, so I am not sure if this is a bug, but it does seem fairly illogical. If this is a bug, where and how do I report it?

Comment: You can clearly see that the weights are correct on per-level setting. Remove the relations and you can set whatever order you like.

Comment: "You can clearly see that the weights are correct on per-level setting". Im not sure what you mean. I clearly entered my own values, and these were not saved. This would seem like a bug. There is no UI feedback saying "I will ignore your input and revert to previously settings". It seems very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue summary is: Drupal seems unable to save changes to taxonomy weight.

Taxonomy weights are saved according to the taxonomy hierarchy rules as pointed out by @RaisinBranCrunch and @IvanJaros. However based on comments in those answers, the real issue seems to be

> Drupal does not give immediate feedback when changing taxonomy weight of children to non-valid values when using visible weights.

This is probably a behavioral bug or feature request that you could post on drupal.org as part of the Drupal project. It would most likely go under either the taxonomy component/module. Although the weight UI system is used in various other places in Drupal core.

It is not a major or critical bug because it does not cause data loss, render the system inoperable, is a security issue, or have significant repercussions (documented here https://www.drupal.org/core/issue-priority).

Whether the bug is accepted or not is another matter. It could be more valuable or important to not kick the user back based on an user input mistake of understanding weight ordering and children.

It may be better to classify this as a feature request because the intent is to change the behavior of the user interface for a different user experience. It is also possible to alter this user experience using Drupal's form alter hook to provide such validation and require explicit knowledge of weight ordering when not using drag and drop.

For more information about how to report an issue to Drupal core, read [How to create a good issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/73179) and start at the [Drupal core issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal).

Answer (score 1):

Animal and Fruit are on the same hierarchical level, so they are sorted like so:

Animal (7)
Fruit (11)

Fruits are sorted like so:

Apple (0)
Orange (1)
Banana (2)

You can't tell Drupal to ignore Hierarchy.  Fruit is the parent of Apple, so it will always be listed above it to represent that it is the parent taxonomy.

Comment: "You can't tell Drupal to ignore Hierarchy." I did not tell Drupal to ignore the hierarchy. I told it to, no longer use the old values, instead use the new values, which it ignored.